# Issue with Pseudo Class Before and After

Tags: css

Is it possible to keep text center and middle aligned within the content provided in the pseudo element before and after? I am trying to keep a paragraph centered in the middle of the brackets.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6dofq3z/

```
p:before {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    content: "{";
    color: #F1722E;
    font-size: 90px;

}

p:after {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    content: "}";
    color: #F1722E;
    font-size: 90px;

}
```

Comment: Think about the code you're writing. Why would one brace be 150px tall and the other be 50px tall? What happens when the width of the paragraph changes...what happens to the height/position of your braces? Also, floats ignore document flow so using them totally ignores the location of the paragraph.

Comment: U have given float - you cant then align them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, position them absolutely and use translations to ensure vertical-alignment:

```
p {
    position: relative;
}

p::before {
    content: "{";
    left: 0;
}

p::after {
    content: "}";
    right: 0;
}

p::before, p::after {
    top: 50%;
    color: #F1722E;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/c6dofq3z/3/

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you would want to use some `relative` and `absolute` positioning, you will also have to set a width for the paragraph.

```
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6dofq3z/1/